# Nested class (Object Type) in PL/SQL

Tags: java, oracle, oop, plsql, object-type

In Java it's possible to define recursive(nested) class like:

```
private class Node
{
  Item item;
  Node next;
}
```

Is it possible to create similar structure using PL/SQL Object Types?

Comment: Did the answers below helped you to understand what you were asking. You can accept either of the answers if they worked for you for future readers reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such option,

But according to Oracle docs about [Nested Object Types](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DMPRG/GUID-EE26B994-34FE-469F-934E-6989416F33FF.htm), you should use `Collection` to hold same types (without recursion)

> Collection types are object data types for modeling multi-valued attributes. Nested tables are collection types

For example:

> ```
> describe dm_nested_categoricals
> DM_NESTED_CATEGORICALS TABLE OF SYS.DM_NESTED_CATEGORICAL
> ```

Comment: This is an example of a nested table of object types, but that is not the same as a recursively defined object type. I do not believe you can do this in Oracle Database object types.

Answer (score 2):

Well you can circumvent the obvious self-referential issue with substitutable types, as below.

```
CREATE TYPE item_t
AS 
   OBJECT (
      attr_a VARCHAR2 (30));
/

CREATE TYPE base_node_t
AS
   OBJECT (
      item item_t)
      NOT FINAL 
      NOT INSTANTIABLE;
/

CREATE TYPE node_t
   UNDER base_node_t (
      next_node base_node_t);
/

DECLARE
   nodes node_t := 
      node_t (
         item_t ( 'grandparent'),
         node_t (
            item_t ( 'parent'),
            node_t (
               item_t ( 'child'),
               NULL)));
BEGIN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
      XMLTYPE (nodes).getclobval (0, 2));
END;
/

<NODE_T>
  <ITEM>
    <ATTR_A>grandparent</ATTR_A>
  </ITEM>
  <NEXT_NODE>
    <ITEM>
      <ATTR_A>parent</ATTR_A>
    </ITEM>
    <NEXT_NODE>
      <ITEM>
        <ATTR_A>child</ATTR_A>
      </ITEM>
      <NEXT_NODE/>
    </NEXT_NODE>
  </NEXT_NODE>
</NODE_T>
```

However I don't believe such types can be declared as column data types and hence persist them directly in relational tables (although indirect methods such as inside anydata or converted to xml would work).

Also I haven't really used this in a real scenario, I don't know if there is a recursion limit or how robust this is generally.

Answer (score 1):

> it is possible to define recursive(nested) class

Yes it's possible to do it but only to achieve `inheritance`. While creating the object you have to make sure its not `Final`. See below demo:

```
--Created an Object which is not `Final`
    CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE prnt_obj AS OBJECT (
        id     NUMBER,
        name   VARCHAR2(10)
    )
    NOT INSTANTIABLE NOT FINAL; --<-- This make sure that the object can be nested.
    /
    --Created a type where the above table columns can be nested.
    CREATE OR REPLACE  TYPE chld_obj UNDER prnt_obj (
        chld_id     NUMBER,
        chld_name   VARCHAR2(10)
    );
    /
    --Created a table of Object.
    CREATE TABLE TAB of chld_obj;
    /
    --Inserted record to the table
    INSERT INTO tab VALUES (
        1,
        'XXX',
        2,
        'YYY'
    );
    --selected records
    SELECT * FROM tab;
    /
```